# Game API Animation loop

Tags: javascript

I'm making a simple game for a project, and I have an issue with one of the features. The enemy ship, moving along the y axis on the right hand side, is supposed to fire shots every 3 seconds in a straight line. The problem I have is that the shots(small yellow circles) are shot from the ship's position and therefore follow the ship on the y axis once shot. Would anyone have any suggestion as to how making the shot follow a straight line and still being fired from the moving ship?
https://codepen.io/Built-to-Code/pen/vZJdYz

```
    var tank = {
    x: 10,
    y: 10,
    width: 10,
    height: 15,
    cx: 115 + 0.5 * 10,
    cy: 65 + 0.5 * 15,
    angle: 0,
    speed: 100
  };

  var enemy = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 10,
    height: 80,
    speed: 1
  }

  var weapon = {
    x: 955,
    y: 10,
    r: 3
  }

  var weapon2 = {
    y: 70
  }

  var distanceToMove = function(delta, speed) {
    return (speed * delta) / 1000;
  }

  var measureFPS = function(newTime) {
    if(lastTime === undefined) {
      lastTime = newTime;
      return;
    }
    var diffTime = newTime - lastTime;

    if(diffTime >= 1000) {
      fps = frameCount;
      frameCount = 0 ;
      lastTime = newTime;
    }
    fpsContainer.innerHTML = "FPS: " + fps;
    frameCount++;
  };

  function timer(currentTime) {
    var delta = currentTime - oldTime;
    oldTime = currentTime;
    return delta;
  }

  function clearCanvas() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
  }

  function drawTank(x, y) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(x, y);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#ffa64d";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#b1b181"
    ctx.strokeRect(100, 50, 40, 15);
    ctx.strokeRect(100, 80, 40, 15);
    drawCanon(tank.cx, tank.cy, tank.angle);
    ctx.restore();
  }

  function drawCanon(cx, cy, angle) {
    ctx.translate(cx, cy);
    ctx.rotate(angle);
    ctx.translate(-cx, -cy);
    ctx.fillRect(115, 65, 10, 15);
    ctx.strokeRect(125, 72.5, 5, 2);
  }

  function updatetankPosition() {
    tank.speedX = tank.speedY = 0;

    if (inputStates.left) {
      //ctx.fillText('left', 150, 20);
      tank.speedX = -tank.speed;
    }
    if (inputStates.right) {
      //ctx.fillText('right', 150, 50);
      tank.speedX = tank.speed;
    }
    if (inputStates.up) {
      //ctx.fillText('up', 150, 80);
      tank.speedY = -tank.speed;
    }
    if (inputStates.down) {
      //ctx.fillText('down', 150, 120);
      tank.speedY = tank.speed;
    }
    if (inputStates.space) {
      //ctx.fillText('space bar', 160, 150);
    }
    if (inputStates.mousePos) {
      /*ctx.fillText("x = " + inputStates.mousePos.x + " y = " +
    inputStates.mousePos.y, 5, 150);*/
    }
    if (inputStates.mousedown) {
      //ctx.fillText("mousedown b" + inputStates.mouseButton, 5, 180);
      tank.speed = 500;
    }else {
      tank.speed = 100;
    }
    tank.x += distanceToMove(delta, tank.speedX);
    tank.y += distanceToMove(delta, tank.speedY);
  }

  function drawEnemy(x, y) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
    ctx.strokeRect(w - enemy.width, y, enemy.width, enemy.height);
    drawEnemyWeapons();
    ctx.restore();
  }

  function drawEnemyWeapons() {
    ctx.save();
    ctx. strokeStyle = "green";
    ctx.strokeRect(w - enemy.width - 30, enemy.y + 10, 30, 2);
    ctx.strokeRect(w - enemy.width - 30, enemy.y + 70, 30, 2);
    ctx.restore();
  }

  function moveEnemy() {
    enemy.y += enemy.speed;
    var shot = window.setTimeout(enemyShots, 3000);
    checkEnemyPosition();
  }

  function checkEnemyPosition() {
    if(enemy.y + enemy.height > h || enemy.y <= 0)
      enemy.speed = -enemy.speed;
  }

  function enemyFire(x, y) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(weapon.x, enemy.y + weapon.y, weapon.r, 0, 2*Math.PI);
    ctx.arc(weapon.x, enemy.y + weapon2.y, weapon.r, 0, 2*Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();
  }

  function enemyShots() {
    weapon.x -= 7;
    if(weapon.x <= 0){
      weapon.x = 955;
    }
  }

  var mainLoop = function(time) {
    measureFPS(time);
    delta = timer(time);
    clearCanvas();
    updateGamePadStatus();
    drawTank(tank.x, tank.y, tank.angle);
    drawEnemy(enemy.x, enemy.y);
    enemyFire(weapon.x, weapon.y, weapon.r);
    moveEnemy();
    updatetankPosition(delta);
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
  };
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using `enemy.y` and `enemy.x`, which are not numbers but rather pointers to numbers which update.  You need to pass by value, rather than pass by reference.

Instead, do something like this:

```
function enemyFire(x, y) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
    ctx.beginPath();
    var coords = [ weapon.x, enemy.y + weapon.y, weapon.r ];
    var coords2 = [ weapon.x, enemy.y + weapon2.y, weapon.r ];
    ctx.arc(coords, 0, 2*Math.PI);
    ctx.arc(coords2, 0, 2*Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();
  }
```

Here is a simple example I ran in my node interpreter to demonstrate the difference you get following an assignment as demonstrated above:

```
> var weaponX = 10;
undefined
> var weaponY = 12;
undefined
> var coords = [ weaponX, weaponY ];
undefined
> console.log(coords);
[ 10, 12 ]
undefined
> weaponY = '99999';
'99999'
> console.log(coords);
[ 10, 12 ]
undefined
```

Comment: Sure!  If it works, please mark the answer as correct.  (And if not comment with what happens, so I and/or others can respond accordingly)

Comment: Setting coordinates in an array that way won't work. I'll need to specify the index of the array I want to use. And I don't think the issue lies with the objects properties. I think the issue is that I need to capture the coordinates of the shots when they're being fired and store them outside of the loop, then use them in the loop to make the shot move from the same coordinates.

Comment: Did you actually try it?  I do mostly web work with JS, not game work, but I think there's a decent chance it would work.  Regardless, if you create new vars, set them equal to the object properties, and then stick them into the coords, I think it exits the scope of the object properties and thus won't change.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I'm working on a few things at the moment. Yes, I did try it, but the challenge really is to capture the coordinates outside of the loop so that they're not updated 60 times/s, and then to use those coordinates to make the object move inside the loop.